# PHP Google Drive API with Service Account

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I would like to read a Google Drive folder in my company private domain, so I can access and process result of Google Forms.

Here is a working PHP code :

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='path/to/drive-api.json');

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();        
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');     

$client->setAccessType('offline');   
//$client->setSubject('admin@mydomain.com');
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
```

But with this code I can only access to the drive space of the service account.

I want to uncomment the "setSubject()" line so I can impersonate a real user and access a real folder. But doing that give me this error :

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

My service account has domain-wide delegation and I have added the scope access to the Gsuite domain's Admin console. I have done everything written [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

So how can I impersonate user with a Service account ? Keep in mind that for security reason user can't share content outside of "mydomain.com" and a service account is on ".iam.gserviceaccount.com"

Comment: Seems you are having a propagation issue. If you have done everything you mentioned and you are getting that error, allow 24 hours and then try again. I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Uncomment the line //$client->setSubject('admin@mydomain.com');